# How do I deploy a standalone .exe file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I deploy a standalone .exe file in Visual Studio Code?

I've seen many questions about Visual Studio, but I can't find anything about VSCode, I would be glad if someone could help me.
If it does help, I'm working with .NET projects, and I use to run them by using the command `dotnet run` in the terminal.

Comment: when you run them with `dotnet run` in the terminal in vs code, what happens?

Comment: They run as they should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dotnet build`.
There's also tons of [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#options) you can use.
E.g, set the type of build to 'Release': `dotnet build --configuration Release`

Or use [this great extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kishoreithadi.dotnet-core-essentials).

Comment: The .exe file is the one found in the bin folder, right?

Comment: Exactly, you can then use the parameter configuration to indicate the build type, Release or Debug, e.g: `dotnet build --configuration Release`